# Using carrierwave to upload images to google cloud storage, the file name ends up being saved and not the public link to the image in the bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-cloud-storage, carrierwave

I'm trying to implement image upload to google cloud storage from my rails 4.2 app using the carrierwave gem. Whenever I go to upload the image it is uploaded to the bucket fine but its saved in the db as the original image name e.g. `image.png`, not as the google cloud storage public link for the image e.g. `https://storage.googleapis.com/project/bucket/image.png`

Not too sure what is needed to be done from here to get it saving the public link from the bucket and not just the file name.

carrierwave.rb file

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:                         'Google',
    google_storage_access_key_id:     'key',
    google_storage_secret_access_key: 'secret key'
  }
  config.fog_directory = 'bucket-name'
end
```

uploaders/check_item_value_image_uploader.rb

```
class CheckItemValueImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  #storage :file
   storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "check-item-value-images/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
   def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end

end
```

related gems

```
gem 'gcloud'
gem "fog"
gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.8.6'
gem "mime-types"
```

check_category_item_value model

```
mount_uploader :value, CheckItemValueImageUploader
```

check_category_item_value update method

```
if @check_category_item_value.save 
   flash[:success] = "Successfully updated"
   redirect_to category_items_edit_path(@guide, @category, @category_item)
else
   render 'category_items/edit'
end
```

edit form

```
 <%= form_for(@check_category_item_value) do |f| %>
   <%= f.file_field :value, :value => item_key.value, accept: "image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif, image/png" %>
   <%= f.submit "Submit" %><hr>
 <% end %>
```

The forms works fine but the value saved is the original image name not the google cloud storage public link for the image.

I used the [carrierwave docs](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave), [this post](http://www.tesseractapps.com/2016/carrierwave-uploads-google-cloud-storage/), and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olPk_uHgRyw) by google cloud platform to get what I have now. What am I missing?

**update**

adding `config.fog_public = true` does nothing

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:                         'Google',
    google_storage_access_key_id:     'key',
    google_storage_secret_access_key: 'secret key'
  }
  config.fog_public = true
  config.fog_directory = 'bucket-name'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the link public, please check this config this in your config file:

```
# You may set it false now
config.fog_public = true
```

For filename you may overwrite in your `CheckItemValueImageUploader`, here is an example:

```
class CheckItemValueImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def filename
    "#{model.id}-#{original_filename}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
  end
end
```

Comment: Ive added `config.fog_public = true` to the carrierwave.rb file (You can see what the file no looks like from my update). I also added in the filename method. but it end up saving the file as`'8-{file.name}.png` in the db

Comment: The update gives the error `undefined method 'name' for #<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x007fd1d4a95530>` on `file.name` (by the way I appreciate the help)

Comment: Hmm sorry, I should use origin filename instead

Comment: Ok I see whats happening here, its doesnt save the full url of the file in the db, it saves it as the same name as what it is saved as in the db, I can then grab it by having something like ` `'https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/check-item-value-images/' + 'check_item_value.image'` right? or is their a built in way carrierwave has to get it. And `#{file.extension}` isnt needed it ends up saving as `9-default.png.png` with it and `9-default.png` without it, remove this from your answer and i'll mark it as correct.